# mysql multi count with WHERE

Tags: mysql, count

i have the following query i made:

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) AS item_count,
 reseller_id, count(**WHERE sold=1**) as sold_count
 count(**WHERE refunded=1**) as rrefunded
 FROM store GROUP BY
 reseller_id
```

sold is either 1 or 0 and same for refund.

I want to check each reseller how much they sold and how much refunded, but I don't have a clue on how to do it in one query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if its 1 or 0 you can do SUM()

```
SELECT SUM(sold) as sold_count, SUM(refunded) as refund_count FROM store
```

Comment: @TDSii: You should unaccept my answer and accept this one instead - I missed the part of your post that said `sold is either 1 or 0 and same for refund`, and therefore my CASE usage is unnecessary. I'm giving Dmitriy a +1 myself. :)

Comment: i know, but yours will be handy in the future and i am here to learn new stuff, but i missed this sum() as well, yet i will change best answer upon your request. thanks for both!

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT 
  reseller_id,
  COUNT(*) AS item_count,  
  sum(case sold when 1 then 1 else 0 end) as sold_count,
  sum(case refunded when 1 then 1 else 0 end) as refunded_count
FROM store
GROUP by reseller_id
```